# Convert NVARCHAR containg Timezone info to DATETIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have the following `NVARCHAR` field is `SQL Server`:

```
Sun Mar 26 23:47:06 GMT+03:00 2017
```

I wish to convert it to `DATETIME` in `tSQL`. How can I do that??? Using the `CONVERT()` and `CAST()` functions returns the following error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have tried converting to `DATETIME`, `DATE`, `DATETIME2`, `DATETIMEOFFSET` and none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Declare @dt varchar(50)
set @dt = 'Sun Mar 26 23:47:06 GMT+03:00 2017'
select CAST(left(stuff(stuff(@dt, 1, 4, ''), 8, 0, right(@dt, 4) + ' '), 20) as DATETIME)
```

**Result**

2017-03-26 23:47:06.000

Comment: so long as you decide the offset is meaningless.